# SQL Server Function to calculate minutes from hours and minutes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to convert a value in H.M format in the a field like (1.2 means 1 hour 20 min) to 80 minutes?
i tried to use a function func_Split to split the Hours and minutes but got stuck on how to add the hours to minutes and bring the result to the select query.

Answer (score 0):

A handy function you can use for this is `parsename`

```
declare @value decimal(4,2)=1.2

select ParseName(@value,2)*60 + ParseName(@value,1)
```

Comment: That's quite some hack you've got there :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be with some arithmetic on the integer and decimal place values:

```sql
SELECT (CONVERT(int,YourColumn) * 60) + ((YourColumn % 1) * 100)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Note that this specifically only works if `YourColumn` is a `decimal` type, not if it's `float` or `varchar` (the OP didn't specify).

Comment: One would *really* hope the OP *isn't* using a `float` or `varchar` mind, @JeroenMostert . They are both the wrong data types for storing time (periods) as a numerical value.

Comment: Though I must also admit that `1.2` representing 1 hour 20 minutes makes little sense either. 1.2 hours is 1 hour 12 minutes.

Comment: Certainly that's obvious -- as obvious as `1.2` being the wrong approach to storing a period in minutes regardless, which makes me expect the worst. :P

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TimeSpent))
FROM yourtable
```